# Want to get an access_token from Twitter Oauth api using oauth.js plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, token

I am trying to get a Twitter access token from their oauth api. The plugin I am using is this https://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/#svn%2Fcode%2Fjavascript. So far I only get "401 failed to validate signature and token".

Strange thing is that my ajax call becomes 'GET' request even though I set type:'POST'. Seems like jquery is changing the type from POST to GET. I don't know why it does that. I am running it on my Mac. I appreciate your help/hints/suggestions/advises. Thanks!

```
$(function() {

    function myCallback(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    }
    var TwitterAPI;

    TwitterAPI = (function() {
    var consumer_key = null;
    var consumer_secret = null;

    function TwitterAPI(cons_key, cons_secret) {
        this.consumer_key = cons_key;
        this.consumer_secret = cons_secret;
    }

    TwitterAPI.prototype._url = function (data) {
            if (typeof data == 'array') {
        return array_map([ // TODO
            this, '_url'], data);
            } else if ((/boolean|number|string/).test(typeof data)) {
        return encodeURIComponent(data).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
            } else {
        return '';
            }
    }

    TwitterAPI.prototype.myCallback = function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }

    TwitterAPI.prototype.getRequestToken = function() {
        var accessor = {
        consumerSecret: this.consumer_secret,  //this.consumer.consumerSecret, 
        tokenSecret: ''
        };

        var message = {
        method: "POST", 
        action: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
        parameters: { 
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1", 
            oauth_consumer_key: this.consumer_key,  //this.consumer.consumerKey
            oauth_callback:    this._url("http://127.0.0.1/foobar/libs/oauth/wtf.html"),
        }
        };
        OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
        OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
        var target = OAuth.addToURL(message.action, message.parameters);
        message.parameters.oauth_signature = this._url(message.parameters.oauth_signature);

        console.log(message.parameters);

        $.ajax("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
           {   url: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               jsonp: 'callback',
               jsonpCallback: "myCallback",
               data: message.parameters,
               success: function(data, textResp, xhr) {
               console.log(data);
               },
               error: function(xhr, text, err) {
               console.log(text);
               }
           });

    };
    return TwitterAPI;
     })();

     api = new TwitterAPI(key, secret);
     $('button#request').on('click', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     api.getRequestToken();
     });
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the URL twice in your $.ajax() call. Try eliminating the first parameter and just sending the options object.  In other words: `$.ajax({url:"...", type:"POST"...` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was trying to experiment all kinds of arg combinations. For this one, I don't think it will have any negative effects. Anyway, I have gave up on this and changed to node-oauth. It works great. I thought this could not be done in a RESTful backend but it actually was possible.